# Software for implementing QR codes for XML Publisher Reports

Tags: windows, xml, qr-code

I'm currently looking for software that could help in employing QR Codes to my Invoices. My company generates invoices using XML Publisher Reports and we're looking to add QR Codes as a customer requirement. We lack sufficient knowledge to handle this task and hope to find any software that could assist in this enhancement. Any recommendations about how to code it in can also be helpful.

Budget-wise, we're still considering our options so it shouldn't be a factor. For now, we're looking at any possible fix for adding the QR codes into our invoices.

It should be compatible with Windows OS. It should automatically generate unique QR codes. It must support batch-processing (though the option to create manual QR codes might be helpful for single invoices). We need to add the QR Code into an existing invoice (which is done using XML Publisher Reports). Special requirements not defined yet, but you can assume that the QR Code would be used to open a link for now.

Comment: Yeah, my company is open to exploring only software. It should be compatible with Windows OS. It should automatically generate unique QR codes. Yes, it must support batch-processing (though the option to create manual QR codes might be helpful for single invoices). We need to add the QR Code into an existing invoice (which is done using XML Publisher Reports). Special requirements not defined yet, but you can assume that the QR Code would be used to open a link for now.

Thanks for the assist!!!

Comment: Thanks, integrated that with your question (note you always can [edit] your post yourself). As it's still not fully clear: What should the QR represent? The info you want to put inside is "plain ASCII" I assume? How large are your batches? Must it run local, or would a SaaS (Software as a Service) be acceptable as well?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you are using XML Publisher in a batch mode with inputs that include:

- Customer Number
- Invoice Number
- Line Items with Item Counts, Unit Prices & Item Total
- Invoice Total
- Some Tax details

A quick, simple & free solution would be to generate a QR code that at least in part included the Customer & Invoice Numbers *this should give you your uniqueness.*

One solution would be to install [Python 3](https://www.python.org/) and the [qrcode](https://github.com/lincolnloop/python-qrcode) library with its dependencies.

Once python is installed you can install the qrcode library *and all of its dependencies* with from the command line with `pip install qrcode Pillow` - then a simple script should be able to extract the Customer & Invoice numbers, format them into a URL and generate the appropriate QR code which can be inserted into the invoice. You will also have a command line for generating one off QR codes, e.g.:

```
> qr https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/69969/software-for-implementing-qr-codes-for-xml-publisher-reports
█████████████████████████████████████████████████████
█████████████████████████████████████████████████████
████ ▄▄▄▄▄ █ ▀▀ ██▄█▄▀█▀ ▀▀ ▀█▄▀ ▀▄▀ ██▀▄█ ▄▄▄▄▄ ████
████ █   █ █▄▀███▀ █▄  ██▀▄▄ ▀▄█▀▀▀▀  █ ▀█ █   █ ████
████ █▄▄▄█ █▄ ▄ ███▄  ▀▄ ▄▄▄     ▀▄ ▄█▄▄▄█ █▄▄▄█ ████
████▄▄▄▄▄▄▄█▄▀▄█ ▀ ▀ ▀ ▀ █▄█ ▀ ▀ ▀▄▀▄█▄█ █▄▄▄▄▄▄▄████
████ ▀▀▄ ▄▄▄ █ ▀  ██▀▀ ▄▄ ▄▄ █ ▀▄▀▀▀▀▀▀ ▀▄▀▀▄▀▄ ▄████
████  █▀█▀▄▀█ ▄▀▀ █▀█▄▄▀ ▀ ▀██▀▄█▀▀▄ ▄ █▄▄█▄█▄▀▄▄████
█████▀▄ ▀▀▄▄▀ ▀▀▀ ▀▀ █▄▄█▄███▀ █▄▄▀▀ ▀▄▀▀█▀▄▄ ▀ █████
████▄▄▀█ █▄█  █▄ ▀█▀  ▄▄ █  ▄█ ▄▄█▀███▀ █▄ ▀█▄ ▄█████
████▄ █▀▀▄▄▄██▄ ▀▀▀ ▀▀▄▄██▀ ▄ ▄ █▄▀   ▀█▀██▀█▄██ ████
████▀ ▀█  ▄▄▄▄ ▄  ▀▀▀█▄█▀▀█  ▀▀▀  █▀▄ ▀▀█▄██▀▀ ▀▄████
████ ▄█▄ ▄▄▄ ▄▄ ██ ▄█▄▄  ▄▄▄    ▄ ▀█▀  ▀ ▄▄▄  ▀▄█████
█████▀█▄ █▄█ █▀▀▀ █▄▄▀█▄ █▄█  ▀█▄▄▀█▀ ▄▀ █▄█ ▄  ▄████
█████▀▄▄▄ ▄  █ ▀ ▀▄ ▄█▀█▄▄ ▄▄▄▀▀▄  █ ▀██▄▄  ▄▀▀ ▄████
████▀▄▀█▄ ▄▀▄▄▄█ ▀ ▄█▄▀▄▄ ▄▀▀█▄▀▄▀█▀▄ ▀▀▄▀█ █ ▀▀█████
████▄▄▀ ▀▀▄ ▀▀▀▄▄██▄█ ▀████▄ ▄▄▀▀█   ▀▀ ▀█▀▀ ▄█▀ ████
████▄▀███▀▄ ██  █▄▄██▀  ▀█▄▄ ▀▀█ ▀▀▄▄ ▀▀  ▄▄▄▀ █▄████
██████  █▀▄██▄▄▀▄ █▀█ ▀ ▄█▄▄▀▄ █▄  █▀  ██▀▄ ▀██▀▄████
█████▀▀▀ █▄▀█ █▄█ █▄▄▀▄█▀█▄▄▀▀██▄██▄ ▄▄█ ▄ ▀█▄  ▄████
████▄██▄▄█▄▄ ▀▀▄  ▄▀██▀  ▄▄▄ ▄    ▀█▄▀▄  ▄▄▄  ▀ ▄████
████ ▄▄▄▄▄ █ █▀ █▀ █▀█ ▀ █▄█ █ ▄▄▄█▄█▀▀  █▄█ ▀ █▀████
████ █   █ █  ▀██ ▀▄▄ ▄▀  ▄▄  ████  ▄  █▄  ▄▄█▀▀▀████
████ █▄▄▄█ ██▀  ▄▄▄█   ▀█▄ ▀██▀▄ ▄▀█▄▀██ █ █ █ ▀ ████
████▄▄▄▄▄▄▄█▄▄█▄█▄█▄▄▄▄█████▄▄▄█▄█████▄█▄▄▄█▄████████
█████████████████████████████████████████████████████
▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀
```

or: `qr --factory=pil https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/69969/software-for-implementing-qr-codes-for-xml-publisher-reports > question.png` which gives an output file:
[image: QR Code]

Pricing & Licence

All of the tools are available free, for commercial use & on multiple platforms.